# Blindly converting a bytearray to a structure?

Tags: c#, c++, data-structures

Is it possible to, say, convert a byte array passed from an older C++ application to C# without exactly knowing what the structure is?

I'm trying to re-make an old application that our company uses, but the source code is no longer available. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hello,

The structure traslation is called marshalling....

you can use Marshal.PtrToStructure function to do that. But I think that you have to know how the structure is defined. Anyway you have to know at list the structure layout. you can find documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Now that's what it's called. Although, I found that the byte array being sent isn't much complex as I expected that it would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to know something about the structure of the byte array if you want to actually use the data embedded in the array.  Without that information, the array is nothing but bytes - you could easily pull it in as bytes, but that will be of little use.

If this information is unavailable, you could use a [hex editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) to try to reverse engineer the byte data.

Comment: I have converted the byte array to hex, and then to string. And apparently I got myself a delimited string. Thank you very much for the hex editor tip!

Answer (score 1):

You could always cast the address of the first byte as a Type * and hope that it works. There maybe be some sizing issues with 32 and 64 bits OS though it really depends on how the c++ code was compiled. The thing is you have to know the type you want to cast to. you could use the size of the byte array as an indicator maybe or use pointer arithmetic to read the fields. In this case you would have to know information about the structure if not it all just looks like bytes to you.